# Problem using aspose-words after exe generation by auto-py-exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, aspose.words

1. Hi,  I think I am lost. Any help? I need to create an executable
   file with my python code, when I run the file give the errors below.
   Thank you all My code:

   ---

   ```
   import aspose.words as aw namePDF = 'NF-TESTE.pdf' doc =
   aw.Document(namePDF) nameTXT = namePDF.strip('.pdf')
   doc.save(nameTXT + ".txt")
   ```

   Then I generate an .exe using auto-py-to-exe. I execute the EXE file
   created and then give me the error:

   ```
   File "<frozen
   importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen
   importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked   File
   "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 672, in _load_unlocked   File
   "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 640, in
   _load_backward_compatible KeyError: 'aspose.pygc'
   The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
   ImportError: One or more errors occurred while loading the module
   'aspose.pygc' (-2) The above exception was the direct cause of the
   following exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
   "aspose\__init__.py", line 44, in load_module   File
   "aspose\__init__.py", line 76, in _load_native_module ImportError:
   One or more errors occurred while loading the module
   'aspose.pydrawing' (-1) The above exception was the direct cause of
   the following exception: ImportError: One or more errors occurred
   while loading the module 'aspose.pydrawing' (-2) The above exception
   was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most
   recent call last):   File "pdfTXTTest.py", line 14, in <module>
       import aspose.words as aw   File "aspose\__init__.py", line 44, in load_module   File "aspose\__init__.py", line 76, in
   _load_native_module ImportError: One or more errors occurred while loading the module 'aspose.words' (-1) [5988] Failed to execute
   script 'pdfTXTTest' due to unhandled exception!
   ```

   ---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`aspose-words` package is a Python binary extensions. By default, binary dependencies are not copied to the output directory by the `PyInstaller` (`auto-py-to-exe`). Therefore, you should explicitly specify some additional options for binary files.

These options should help:

```
--collect-binaries "aspose" --collect-submodules "aspose"
```