# missing module aspose in file exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, aspose

I wrote a program which combines two or more PDFs in one and converts PDFs in Jpeg or PNG files.

I tried to create the .exe file but the "aspose" module was not found.

I used these command (I found a sample in this question with the same problem [Problem using aspose-words after exe generation by auto-py-exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72653069/problem-using-aspose-words-after-exe-generation-by-auto-py-exe):

```
myDirectory CombinaPDF_004.py --onefile --collect-binaries "aspose" --collect-submodules "aspose"
```

What else could I do?

Comment: It would be nice if you could post your solution as an answer so future readers can find it more easily.

Comment: Not only nice, that is necessary. Questions ask. Answers answer. Questions should not answer. (And answers should not ask, but that is a different problem....)

Answer (score 1):

Example of how to create one-file bundled executable using PyInstaller (https://pyinstaller.org):

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --collect-binaries "aspose" --collect-submodules "aspose" path/to/script
```

Its works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

'Digital.qubit' answer didn't work for me as it missed a step. My aspose modules being imported in my script are aspose.slides and aspose.pydrawing

The steps i took include:

- Open command prompt
- change directory to where your python script is located using the following command

  cd path/to/script
- Enter in the command

  pyinstaller --noconsole --collect-binaries "aspose" --collect-submodules
  "aspose.slides" script_name.py

To check if you need to include any submodules, check your imports in your script file, if your aspose import is it's own folder separate to aspose found in site packages (Mine is located here 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages')

Then include it in the submodules quotations.

**FOR EXAMPLE** aspose.pydrawing is included in the aspose folder in site-packages so i didn't need to add it as a sub-module command as it is already included when pyinstaller collects the aspose-binaries through the '--collect-binaries "aspose"' command.

Hit enter on your command prompt to create the exe file.

After you have done this, navigate to your pythons site packages folder again usually located here ^

'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages'

and copy the aspose and aspose submodule folder, in my case it was "Apose.Slides-22.8.0.dist-info", into your 'dist/application_folder/' created when pyinstaller is finished. When it asks if you want to replace the files or skip, select Skip.

Launch the application and your ready to go.

Not sure if the op managed to get his working but hopefully this helps other people that have run into this issue