# Desktop Application: Conversion from .py to .exe

Tags: python

The following issue has occured while converting. (the error photo)

[image: Please use [the following link][1] to see]

The opening code for main.py:

```py
# The Imported items.
import sys
import os
import io

if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    os.environ['PATH'] = sys._MEIPASS + ';' + os.environ['PATH']

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QListWidget, \
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QComboBox, QStylePainter, \
    QDialog, QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QAbstractItemView, QStyle, QStyleOptionComboBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPainter, QPalette

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger  # PDF Merger
from aspose.cells import Workbook, SaveFormat  # Excel Converter
from docx2pdf import convert  # Document Converter
```

Comment: From Googling `InputFormatMode.KEEP_SOURCE_FORMATTING`, it seems you are using Aspose Words for Python via .NET. This also explains what `aw` is, and explains why you are getting a .NET error message in Python code. I would not expect this library to throw .NET exceptions at you, so I suspect the thing to do here is to seek support (either free or paid) from Aspose themselves.

Answer (score 0):

### **Answer: Desktop Application: Conversion from .py to .exe**

This issue is based on aspose's messy creation process.

After a little bit of research on many alternate platforms, this answer pops up:

`Adding --hiddenimport=aspose.pydrawing --hiddenimport=aspose.pygc --collect-binaries=aspose to the build command gets it past the aspose imports.`

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73194238/missing-module-aspose-in-file-exe-solved) is over on this question here as well: